# WildFly 10. Is it possible to configure multiple JNDI?

Tags: jms, wildfly-10

WildFly 10. Is it possible to configure multiple JNDI ? So that was a common topic.

standalone-full-ha.xml:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:naming:2.0">
        <bindings>
            <external-context name="java:/global/Server" module="org.jboss.as.naming" class="javax.naming.InitialContext" cache="true">
                <environment>
                    <property name="java.naming.factory.initial" value="org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory"/>
                    <property name="java.naming.provider.url" value="http-remoting://172.16.2.1:8080"/>
                    <property name="java.naming.security.principal" value="jms"/>
                    <property name="java.naming.security.credentials" value="jms"/>
                </environment>
            </external-context>
            <lookup name="java:global/ExportedTopic" lookup="jms/topic/MyTopic"/>
            <lookup name="java:global/ExportedFactory" lookup="java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory"/>
        </bindings>
        <remote-naming/>
    </subsystem>
```

Comment: Yes, I think it's possible. Could you be more specific what's your target?

Comment: In order to ensure work in a cluster environment  https://developer.jboss.org/message/965989#965989